3D transformation(rotation) of cube does not work as expected
I am writing a 3D engine without using matrices but the rotation for it is not working
currently I am using this code for the rotation:
vertex.x = vertex.x * cos(theta) - vertex.y * sin(theta)
vertex.y = vertex.y * cos(theta) + vertex.x * sin(theta)

however it is not working and squishes the cube while rotating it:
currently I am only trying to rotate on one axis(z)
Cube mid rotation:

no rotation:

cubes in 3D with no rotation

cubes in 3D with "rotation"

the path of the rotation of a line from a top down perspective with the first vertex rotating around the origin (0, 0, 0)
I just want the cubes to rotate as you would expect.
what is the correct maths this?

Welcome! Pure maths questions should be asked on math StackExchange. Here on SO, an answer would be a snippet of code that works. Which language are you using and could you provide a minimal working example?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Typical vector/matrix operations mistake:
vertex.x = vertex.x * cos(theta) - vertex.y * sin(theta)
vertex.y = vertex.y * cos(theta) + vertex.x * sin(theta)   <<<--- x is already new here!

In shorter terms:
x = x * a + y * b
y = y * a + x * b   <<<--- x is already new here!

Example:
x == 5, y == 3, a == 2, b == 4
x = 5 * 2 + 3 * 4
y = 3 * 2 + 22 * 4   <<<--- x is not 5 here, it's 22 already


Never write to the data you keep changing:
newVertex.x = vertex.x * cos(theta) - vertex.y * sin(theta)
newVertex.y = vertex.y * cos(theta) + vertex.x * sin(theta)


the vertex position is set to its original position at the start of every transformation so they can compound. It's not that I am changing the data.

@name I highly doubt that. See the edit.
